# Why do I see the default IIS Windows page shown when trying to view my Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laragon

If you want more information, you should see the video [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xQpYG2YYxk&list=PLpKWS6gp0jd_xJyvkbDzoMQLQc-qyFQAE&index=2) in the minute 4:20 until the end and if you need more information you see the whole video.

Here is the page that I get when I try to open my website laravel9:

[image: default home page]

And here is the route where my page is found:

[image: project folders]

I try to move my file laravel to localhost, but I always get the page IIS Windows and I'm expecting why do I get that? and the answer to fix it.

Comment: Have you read about [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet) for serving your Laravel project on your local machine?

Comment: I don't have read about it

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm forgetting that Valet is for Mac OS and you are using Windows.

Comment: Yes, what should I do?

Comment: In the documentation for [Your First Laravel Project](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#your-first-laravel-project) it says to "start Laravel's local development server using the Laravel's Artisan CLI serve command." and then view the site at the address `http://localhost:8000`. Does that work for you?

Comment: To set up iis on your Windows is very, very difficult. As the people above me said: use `php artisan serve`, use Laracon, use Wampp. Basically anything else than iis.